# View does not open route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following dropdown in my pug file:

```
  .btn-group
    button.btn.btn-danger(type='button') Sort By ASC/DESC
    button.btn.btn-danger.dropdown-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown', aria-haspopup='true', aria-expanded='false')
      span.caret
    ul.dropdown-menu
      li
        a(href='/sortBy/asc/createdAt') ASC  
      li
        a(href='/sortBy/desc/createdAt') DESC
  .btn-group
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='button') Sort By Date
    button.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown', aria-haspopup='true', aria-expanded='false')
      span.caret
    ul.dropdown-menu
      li
        a(href='/sortBy/asc/createdAt') Created At  
      li
        a(href='/sortBy/asc/updatedAt') Updated At
```

The route that should handle this looks like the following:

```
router.get('sortBy/:sortBy/:date', sessionChecker.sessionChecker, async(req, res) => {
...
}
```

However, I get:

```
Cannot GET /sortBy/desc/createdAt
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `router.get('/sortBy/:sortBy/:date',....)` ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma The idea is to pass the dropdown values directly to the route. Basically the dropdown is used for sorting.

Comment: He means adding the leading slash `/` should fix the problem